# Passing LocalStorage value to a drop down title

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to pass the `localStorage` value `user_id` as a title of Bootstrap drop down list, But not sure why its not working.

I'm trying to show user's name as a heading/title of drop down list items with the help of `localStorage`, whatever input user gives in 'user_id' should be used as heading/title of drop down list.

```js
function validateLogin() {
  var profile_name = document.getElementById('user_id').value();
  localStorage.setItem("userID", profile_name);
  document.getElementById('profile-ddl').value = localStorage.getItem('userID');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <input class="user_login_form" id='user_id' type="text" required tabindex="1" name="user_id" autofocus autocomplete=off placeholder="User Name" />
</div>

<input class="user_login_submit" type="submit" id='btnLogin' tabindex="3" name="login_btnSubmit" value="Submit" onsubmit="return validateLogin()" />

<li class="dropdown">
  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" id='profile-ddl' aria-expanded="false"> <span class="caret"></span></a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href='#'>Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Setting</a></li>
    <hr/>
    <li class="disabled"><a href='#'>Manage Account</a></li>
    <li class="disabled"><a href='#'>Ledger Account</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Use `.innerHTML` to set the inner HTML content. Anchor elements don't have `value`. `.value` sets the _value_ attribute value.

Comment: Still not working

Comment: A few typos... First, you are binding your func on the `onsubmit` event of a button. The submit event fires on the parent `<form>` of the button, not on the button itself. You might want to wrap your inputs in a `<form>` and listen for this form's submit event, or listen to the button's click event instead. Then, `value` of HTMLInputElement is not a function, remove the `()` when getting. And yes, `<a>` element doesn't have a `value` property, but don't use innerHTML, use .textContent instead, or even, target its span child.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont have value attribute on a tags, instead you can use element.innerHTML.

Comment: try wrapping the input in form element and using button type='submit' instead of using input type='submit'